# Wi-Fi quit working on all of our routers, hardwired still works

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

We've got five separate wireless routers currently configured as access points to allow wireless access to our domain network.  Last night, every single one of them lost wireless capabilities at the same time.

When hard wiring through the router (i.e., connecting the ethernet cable to the router instead of directly into the wall jack) we are able to get internet/network access.  However, when connecting to the router wirelessly there is no network access at all.

We've tried power cycling the routers, to no avail.  Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

It sounds very "conspiracy theory" but the only thing I can think that would cause every single router to fail at the same time (and only the wireless functionality) is a signal jammer of some sort.  Even though it sounds crazy, I tested with a portable broadband hotspot we have and we are able to connect and access internet through that just fine.  I just have no idea what's going on here.

This is on a domain network so the routers are not handling DHCP or anything, they're just providing a wireless means to get into the network.

Comment: -1 for doing it this way to start.  At least one router has to be a master and distributing the actual internet signal

Comment: @Tyson, could you please elaborate?  I apologize, but I'm pretty new to networking in general and especially wireless.  This is on a domain network so the routers are not handling dhcp or anything, they're just providing a wireless means to get into the network.

Comment: Actually I can't without knowing more about you setup, but at least one of the routers must be being a router and the other 4 must be access points.

Comment: Ok, what kind of information do you need?

Comment: Have you run any app or tool to look for other WiFi devices in the area? I run insider on an Android device for this.  I have found many cases where someone nearby installs a device or devices on the same channel and things go bad quickly as the devices "fight" for the channel.  In several cases it was devises that were not broadcasting an SSID.  Channel change solved issue

Answer (score 0):

To measure is to know, try them separately and also in a different location.

Comment: Are you suggesting shutting them all down except one and plug it into a different wall jack?

Comment: @MajorIndustries - Different wall jack, verify each device by itself works, a device that blocks a WiFI signals is easily detected.

Comment: I'm sorry, how does this answer the question? Perhaps the intent is what @Ramhound mentioned, but this is showing up in the "low quality posts" queue, FYI

Comment: @Raystafarian: Yes, this is an idea to what could be causing this.